# How to generate a "conversation" view url with the outlook rest api

Tags: outlook-restapi, outlook-web-app

I want to be able to either get or generate a url that can be opened to show a proper "conversation" view in the outlook web app (outlook.com). I want to be able to see every message in the conversation AND show all the attachments.

Right now the WebLink that is retrieved from the rest api shows a conversation view (if you happen to open the most recent message in a conversation) but DOESNT show the attachments for any of the other messages in the conversation.

very odd.

[image: This is the "converstion" view, as I call it, for the newest message in the conversion. Notice how it doesnt show the attachment.]

[image: If you use the WebLink for just the message with the attachment (this is the oldest message in a conversation)]

For the first picture, this is the "converstion" view, as I call it, for the newest message in the conversion. Notice how it doesnt show the attachment.

For the second picture, if you use the WebLink for just the message with the attachment (this is the oldest message in a conversation), it does show the attachment.